# AngularJS bindings not working when in a template being ng-included

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

While creating a dynamic panel:

```
<div ng-controller="widgetCtrl">
  <div drag-group="widgets">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" ng-repeat="widget in widgets" draggable-widget="widget" draggable-widget-callback="moveWidget">
      <div class="panel-heading" ng-include="widget.header" draggable-widget-handle></div>
      <div ng-include="widget.body"></div>
      <div class="panel-footer" ng-include="widget.footer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From data in an array:

```
var widgets = [{
        title: 'Sites',
        header: 'panel-header-sites.html',
        body: 'include-sites.html',
        footer: 'panel-parent-footer.html'
    }, ...]
```

The bindings within the ng-include (include-sites.html):

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-controller="SiteCtrl as ctrlsite">
  <table class="table-condensed table-fixed table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 ">name</th>
        <th class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 ">connection</th>
        <th class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 ">location</th>
        <th class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 ">contact</th>
        <th class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"><a ng-click="ctrlsite.expandAll(allExpanded = !allExpanded)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="All Details"><i class="zmdi zmdi-more zmdi-hc-2x"></i></a></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat-start="site in ctrlsite.sites">
        <td class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 h-dotted-line">{{site.SiteName}}<br/>
          <span class="tr-secondary-row text-capitalize" ng-repeat="connection in site.Connections">{{connection.ExternalIP}}</span></td> ... </div>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMessages', 'ngResource', 'angular.filter', 'dndLists'])

  .factory('Sites', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('data/sites.json');
  });

app.controller('SiteCtrl', function ($scope, Sites) {
    var self = this;

    console.log("SiteCtrl hit");
    console.log($scope.$id);
    self.sites = Sites.query();

    self.expandAll = function (expanded) {
      // $scope is required here, hence the injection above, even though we're using "controller as" syntax
      $scope.$broadcast('onExpandAll', {
        expanded: expanded
      });
    };

  });
```

Fail because I get the following error:

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.9/ng/areq?p0=SiteCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
```

When all code resides in a single file (index.html) everything works great. I have been hunting for weeks trying to resolve this, but I am very new to AngularJS.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing more of your code / html, but that error from Angular is saying that the SiteCtrl controller doesn't resolve to a function - meaning it never got bootstrapped. It may be an order of inclusion issue, or that you're not wrapping the `app.controller` in a function closure ala `(function() { /*code here*/ })();`

Comment: The HTML all works, it seems the ng-controller and binding don't work as soon as they are moved to an include (ng-include).

Comment: Generally ng-include should afaik be avoided. Can you make it into a separate component?

Comment: I don't follow your comment, can you please clarify and provide example?

Comment: All I can think at this point, without seeing the structure of what you're doing, is that maybe your Angular code isn't in a separate included .js file? `ng-include` creates a new Root Scope (that doesn't inherit) so if your app/controller code is in an HTML script tag on your page, the include might not be able to resolve the controller. Either way, the error you're getting is Angular telling you that it cannot resolve the Controller for whatever reason so it's almost certainly an inclusion / order of inclusion issue. HTH!

Comment: All AngularJS code are in seperate files and being added via Script tag in the index page. Should they be added in the include files instead?